# Disable the "nanny" when running Dask SSHCluster

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed, dask-delayed

Consider an SSHCluster with multiple hosts.

```
cluster = SSHCluster(["localhost", "hostname"],
                    connect_options={"known_hosts": None},
                    worker_options={"n_workers": params["n_workers"], },
                    scheduler_options={"port": 0, "dashboard_address": ":8797"},)

client = Client(cluster)
```

I have tried starting multiple workers on the same host (params["n_workers"] > 1), and found this to be rather wasteful in memory. In fact, I could not even get a successful run, without crashing, very likely due to running out of memory. I don't have these problems with multiprocessing, even when using multiple processes.

I believe a better strategy would be to re-design the worker method to be more fine-grained, and to require smaller input parameters and return smaller output results. This will take me a bit longer to achieve, and in the meantime, I am trying to start 1 worker on each host (params["n_workers"] = 1), and utilise the multiprocessing "pool" in the worker, to parallelise across the available cores in each host. (I would have my own config that decides how many processes to use, etc)

```
manager = mp.Manager()
pool = mp.Pool()
```

I tried it, but got the error:

> AssertionError: daemonic processes are not allowed to have children

Then I tried to create a Dask Distributed scheduler with scheduler = "processes", which seems to utilise a similar approach to the pool method.

```
delayed_values = [delayed(worker)(param) for param in params]
futures = compute(delayed_values, scheduler="processes", num_processes=n_processes)
```

The above code returns the same error. This is likely happening because the "nanny" is creating the workers in multiprocessing processes, and then I am trying to create more processes from within each worker process.

I have found various links suggesting passing the --no-nanny param. See [link1](https://github.com/dask/dask/discussions/7157) which suggests passing --no-nanny to the worker directly, see [link2](https://distributed.dask.org/en/stable/killed.html) which mentions that it is possible to do it via the CLI. But I have not found an example of how to do this programmatically. I am not sure whether this is possible, and if it is possible, how to achieve it (via which object etc). I have tried looking into the Dask code, but have not figured it out.

Comment: Quick note that `scheduler="processes"` is basically avoiding your distributed scheduler completely https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/scheduler-overview.html#using-compute-methods

Comment: https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/deploying-ssh.html?highlight=sshcluster#python-interface has examples of changing the worker/thread mix per host for SSH clusters, and `worker_class=` for avoiding the nanny, if you wish.

Comment: thanks for getting back to me. re your first comment, isn't that what I want though? I want to use the distributed scheduler for the first level of distribution, and the multiprocessing scheduler for further parallelisation in the worker node. re your second comment, the example of changing the worker/thread mix per host seem to indicate that the same settings need to be used on each host (which is not the case for me). re the worker_class= to avoid the nanny, would I have to write some worker class myself or do you have one I could use in mind?

Comment: @mdurant did you have any ideas about the worker_class by any chance?

Comment: https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/worker.html#api-documentation ? But honestly, it feels like this is getting far more complicated than it should be.

Comment: Do you mean the attempt to run the multiprocessing scheduler in the worker mode?

Comment: Correct, it should absolutely not be necessary, when you can specify the number of workers you want, or manually launch processed on your hosts.

Comment: the reason why I am resorting to this is that starting workers, and assigning methods with params to them, is insanely slow, and a large amount of memory is being used. my data collections are large, however, definitely not nearly as large as the memory that is being used. this approach was a last resort, for lack of better avenues. A better approach would be to re-design the worker methods and make them more fine-grained, with smaller inputs and outputs. however, global params are needed, and I still have problems with them (as being tackled in the other ticket you're also helping me with)